# Stripline with coplanar ground plane?

Tags: rf, transmission-line, ground-plane, characteristic-impedance

I can't seem to find any impedance calculator that offers this configuration — not sure if it has a different name; I'm referring to a trace on an inner layer, sandwiched between ground planes on the immediately surrounding layers, but also surrounded by a "ground pour" on the same layer (KiCAD does not include this configuration, and I could not find it in either of the online calculators out there — EEweb, allaboutcircuits, everythingrf, etc.).

Is this a configuration that is avoided for some reason? (if so, can someone explain why, or point me to relevant reading?)

If I go with a stripline, would it be ok to just use via fences? I assume I will need via fences anyway, as striplines will be "tightly packed" and some will be running parallel, approx. 2mm away from each other.

Comment: Coplanar Waveguide.. if you also have planes sandwiching this structure, then the coplanar copper loses its importance pretty much..

Comment: `some will be running parallel, approx. 2mm away`  the absolute distance doesn't matter , it's the separation relative to the ground plane spacing.

Comment: @tobalt ‒ is this the answer to my question? It does make sense (for that matter, when calculating a microstripline vs. a coplanar waveguide with ground plane, the difference is not much (e.g., with KiCAD's calculator, targeting 50Ω: 0.366mm for microstrip line, 0.346mm with 0.2mm space to the coplanar ground plane). I suppose via fences are still a good idea, perhaps with a gap around 3 to 5 times the width of the trace or 3 to 5 times the distance to adjacent layers with ground planes, whichever is larger?

Comment: What I meant by "is this the answer" is that if you want to formulate it as an answer, then I will mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you lay out the return conductor on the same layer as the signal conductor, this is called a *coplanar waveguide*. There are simulators for this around. This configuration provides only rather weak E-field coupling between the signal and return conductors and it is only used if you have only 1 layer to work with or if other layers are very far away.

As a result, whenever there are other copper layers in close proximity (e.g. ~0.1 mm), the coplanar copper becomes essentially meaningless because most of the E-field couples to the neighboring layer, forming stripline or microstrip geometries.

[Here](https://chemandy.com/calculators/coplanar-waveguide-with-ground-calculator.htm) is a calculator for a coplanar waveguide with 1 ground layer. When you set `w` very high you get essentially a microstrip. For testing, I set up a 50 Ω microstrip. Then I brought in the coplanar copper by reducing `w` to 0.2 mm and the impedance reduced to 43.5 Ω. So it is relevant but not very effective.

This also implies that the coplanar copper has barely any additional shielding merit. It is completely fine to lay out parallel signal lines if they respect a little bit of clearance, e.g. 3-5 times the prepreg thickness.